# AutoScaleMode being ignored

Tags: winforms, autoscalemode

I'm writing a WinForms C# application on a 4K laptop in Visual Studio Community 2017. 
By default I have my Windows 10 Pro scaled to 150%. I have AutoScaleMode = none on every form and every user control.

I run my application and yet it still is scaled to 150%. I'm running VS as a DPI unaware process, and at design time my control are the right (small) size. I don't think it matters but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

Running Windows 10 Pro, fully updated.

Comment: So, you probably want to make your app DPIAware.

Comment: How would that fix that? Maybe I'm not understanding how DPIAware works...

Comment: [How can I update my WinForms app to behave better at high DPI, or at normal DPI on very large screens?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=93695) -- [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) -- [Mixed-Mode DPI Scaling and DPI-aware APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-improvements-for-desktop-applications).

Comment: Try first to apply what's described here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103). See how it goes. Note that you can now use the `app.config` file to set the DPIAwareness of your app. The `app.manifest` settings override what is specified in `app.config`.